# ¿Como envio el foco a una etiqueta input desde la actionresult de un controlador?

Tags: asp.net

Estoy comenzando en C# y MVC, ya he hecho unas cosas en VBA, y pensaba en traducir esto a ASP.net MVC5 pero me he encontrado con el problema que antes, en el formulario tenia unos textbox y para enviar el foco a uno de ellos al ocurrir un error, solo ponía textbox.setfocus, pero al ser otro lenguaje y tener otras formas de comunicarse con la interfaz de usuario, no sé como enviarle el foco a un "textbox" en la vista(razor).

He intentado con `form["Campo"].algo();` pero no he tenido ningún resultado que no sea error y en la web sólo encuentro cosas confusas y envios de foco desde la carga de la vista, pero también me dan error al probar uno que otro.

Tienen alguna idea de como podría enviar el foco al campo en la vista, digamos:

```
public actionresult accionDeVista(Formcollection form)
{if(x>0)
{form["campo"].setfocus();
}
else
{
form["campo2"].setfocus();
}
return view();
}
```

Algo así.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar el `ViewBag` para almacenar desde el controlador qué control quieres que tenga el foco y después, mediante javascript, aplicar el foco en dicho elemento. Sería algo así:

**Controlador**

```
public ActionResult accionDeVista(Formcollection form)
{
    if(x>0)
    {
        ViewBag.FocoEn = "campo";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.FocoEn = "campo2";
    }
    return View();
}
```

**Vista**

```
<input type="text" id="campo" />
<input type="text" id="campo2" />

@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.FocoEn) {
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //con javascript puro
        document.getElementById('@ViewBag.FocoEn').focus();

        //o si tienes jQuery
        $('#@Viewbag.FocoEn').focus();
    </script>
}
```

Es muy esquemático, pero te puedes hacer una idea aproximada